# any OCR techniques for java

Tags: java, ocr

I have MCA final year project to extract data from image (jpg, gif, etc.).
I want to recognize data from image.
I have used java ocr but it is not working.
Are there any open source libraries which can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at zxing, http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a java based OCR tool](http://abstractnonsense.com/software/ocr.html). The page claims that the tool can recognize triangles and other patterns from letters - they have given sample images too. The code is open source and downloadble.

Did you try [Asprise](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/download.php?lang=java)?

[tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is an open source OCR tool, but it's not in Java. See [tesseract in action](http://asv.aso.ecei.tohoku.ac.jp/tesseract/)

Comment: OCR tool is not working.......

I have used Asprise OCR with linux os.....
but it is not a open source .......

but i m getting problem to run on MAC os

Comment: must you use java? if not, check out tesseract - just updated the post.

Comment: tesseract source code in c++ is available in google code. http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ That's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a trainable OCR that has been used to [break capthcas](http://blogs.zdnet.com/security/?p=1418).  Unfortunately the group that broke the capthcas didn't release source code.   However,  here is [example code](http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele585/OCR/) of training Matlab's ocr.

The matlab code will easily compile into your java project.